# User Verification Link / Message

Tags: registration

I have set user registration to 'Admin' on one of my client websites. There are a number of people responsible for verifying users and clicking the activation approval link.

The activation works fine and is in the following format;

> http://www.example.com/component/rsform/form/4-user-registration?task=plugin&action=user.activate&token=959da6ce849ef5a2cf000818a9407062

However they have mentioned that if they try to click the link after somebody else has already verified the user they receive:

> Error 403 - verification code not found

This means that the user has already been verified by another employee.

This is totally normal and what's supposed to happen I understand.

My question - is there a way of changing this error and displaying something like *'This user has already been verified on xx-xx-xxxx'* Or something similar.

Joomla 3.3

Using RSForms Pro extension for user registration form.

**Update**

I asked RSForms if it's an issue with their plugin and this is their response;

> This is not something that is controlled from the component, but a
>   default Joomla! functionality/error message. In order to change this
>   message you will most likely need to edit the default Joomla! code,
>   unfortunately this exceeds the range of our support policy.

So I would need to edit core code?

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? Are you using any 3rd arty extensions such as Kunena or Community Builder which may be overriding the activation?

Comment: Joomla 3.3 and the only 3rd party extension I am using is RSForms Pro. The user registration for is built with this - could that be the issue? * Updated original question to include this info thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how RS Forms Pro works. It might not generate the correct validation URL or it could be a bug. It would be worth contacting the developer of this extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only change the message, you only have to:

- Visit Extensions / Language Manager / Overrides
- New
- Language Constant: COM_USERS_ACTIVATION_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND
- Text: This user has already been verified

To add the date of previous activation, it's not directly possible, since it's processed by a com_users controller and an associated model. In the case of the error, the controller just shows the label, registration.php, line 51:

```
    // Check for a valid user id.
    if (!$userId) {
        $this->setError(JText::_('COM_USERS_ACTIVATION_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND'));
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: while not a perfect solution, this is as good as you are going to get because Joomla does not store the activation token once a user has been activated. There would be no way to correlate the user with a date or the original user that was activated.

Comment: I've just tried this and it works perfectly. Although not exactly what I was hoping for, it works and provides more information as opposed to 'verification code not found'. Thanks @Anibal and @ Brent Friar